# pydantic + fastapi response schema failed to be validated

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

`schemas.py`

```py
class ExpenseBase(BaseModel):
    Fixed: float
    Variable: float
    Salary: float
    month: int
    year: int

class Expense(ExpenseBase):
    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True
        orm_mode = True

class ExpenseSingle(BaseModel):
    __root__: Expense
    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True
        orm_mode = True
```

In my `main.py`:

```py
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, HTTPException
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

from . import api, models, schemas
from .database import SessionLocal, engine

[...]

@app.get('/expense/{id}/', response_model=schemas.ExpenseSingle)
def read_expense(id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
   
    if id is None or isinstance(id, int) is not int:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="ID is not int")

    expense = api.get_expense_by_id(db, id=id)
    return expense
```

but I get the following **error** when I try to get that API endpoint:

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for ExpenseSingle
response
  none is not an allowed value (type=type_error.none.not_allowed)
```

I have tried to change `schemas.py`, to this:

```py
class ExpenseSingle(BaseModel):
    reponse: None
    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True
        orm_mode = True
```

I can't understand **where** it should be fixed - looks like I didn't understand how `pydantic` and `fastapi` relate to each other...

Comment: What is the return type of `api.get_expense_by_id(db, id=id)`? you might be casting a ExpenseSingle object (return type of get_expense_by_id) into an ExpenseSingle object (as you provided a response_model). That could lead to such validation errors.

Comment: hey @JarroVGIT, thx for trying to help me, I have figured out that the problem was my lack of handling `None` or empty responses from the Database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved when I started to handle empty (`None`) responses from the database with the following code:

```py
if not expense:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="No Expenses found")

return expense
```